# Storing patch variables for future use by individual agents

Tags: netlogo

I have several agents in my world that move around and consume resources as they move. I would like each agent to remember the patches they visited and the value for food (a patch variable) they found when they visited the patch. I would also love to be able to easily store a temporal reference for when the patch was visited so that the remembered value for patches decays with time. I am running into issues trying to find a way to store a patch variable in an agentset that is turtle-specific.

I imagine that I can store a

Right now I have:

```
globals [year]

bears-own
[
  memory-value
  memory-1
  memory-2
  memory-3
]

patches-own
[
  food
]
```

During initialization, year is set to 1 and when agents are created I ask them to set memory-1 patch-here. After 1000 ticks the year value is updated to 2 and after another 1000 ticks it changes to 3. In the go procedure the following procedure is called:

```
to set-memory
  if year = 1
  [
    set memory-1 (patch-set memory-1 patches in-radius 5)
    ask memory-1 [set memory-value food]
  ]
    if year = 2
  [
    set memory-2 (patch-set memory-2 patches in-radius 5)
    ask memory-2 [set memory-value food]
    if ticks = 1001 [ask memory-1 [set memory-value (food * (exp (- year)))]]
  ]
end
```

I believe this code is using the same memory-1, memory-2, and memory-3 agentsets for all agents so that they all have access to patches visited by other agents. I would like agents to only be able to "remember" the patches they had access to. I'm also not sure whether my approach to the temporal part is accurate. I have a feeling I might need to use the matrix extension but thought I'd get some insight before I delve into the unknown. Any help in solving this or improving clarity of the question are much appreciated!

Comment: Have you had a look at the table extension? Each turtle can have a separate table for each of the variables for food amount and time, or you can have both variables as a single (list) value in one table. You set up the table with the key as the (list) pair of patch coordinates.

Comment: Hi Jen, thanks for the advice! I'm looking into this now but am wondering how I would then be able to create a procedure that asks each turtle to access their own list. Thanks for helping with this :)

Comment: If the turtle has a variable called mytable which is set up as a table, then `table:get mytable [xval yval]` or similar would retrieve the table's value for the given patch. I will do an answer which doesn't answer your question but gives a similar type of manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `table` extension for this sort of issue. This is an extract that does something similar, but is simpler than your problem. Each turtle keeps track of the patches it visits and the number of visits to that patch. The variable this is stored in is called mapAware and each turtle has its own map.

```
extensions [table]

turtles-own [mapAware]

to setup
  ...
  ask turtles
  [ set mapAware table:make
  ]
  ...
end

go
  ...
  update-awareness
  ...
end

to update-awareness
  ask turtles
  [ let thisPatch (list pxcor pycor)    ; key for table
    let oldVisits table:get-or-default mapAware thisPatch 0
    table:put mapAware thisPatch oldVisits + 1
  ]
end
```

Comment: Hi Jen, if I understand correctly the procedure works by first creating a list that contains the patch coords (key), then setting a default value for that key = 0, and then changing that value to be (0) + 1. I feel like this is totally how I need to do it. However, I am lost on how I might add multiple patches at once (e.g. all neighbors), update all table values at once (when year changes) and how I could get my turtles to access table values and add those to the new value of the patch. If a new question would be best let me know!

Comment: No, there is not an initial list. The table only contains keys for patches that have been visited. The `get-or-default` makes sure that an entry in the table that's not already there is set to 0 rather than an creating an error. I think you probably need to start doing this and have a few prints before asking an extra question. You have a lot of things going on. If you try and do this, you can ask a specific question on the bit you get stuck on.

Comment: I have created a new question that asks a more specific thing that I am currently stuck on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57066138/memory-storing-patch-variables-in-table-for-multiple-patches